# How do I show the sequence converge to zero in measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $X=[0,1]$ with a Lebesgue measure. Let $f_n(x)=x^n$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Prove that $f_{n}$ converge to zero in measure.

My idea: Clearly, $f(x)= 0 $ for $0 \leq x <1$, and $1$ for $x=1$, then by definition

$\mu(\{x: |x^{n}|\geq 1\}) \rightarrow$ $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Is this solution correct?

Answer (score 4):

For any $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, the set $\{x\in[0,1];x^n\geqslant\epsilon\}$ is the interval $[\epsilon^{1/n},1]$ and is (Lebesgue) measure is $1-\epsilon^{1/n}$ which tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the simplest solution is the following:
$f_n$ converges a.e. to $f = 0$, moreover X has finite Lebesgue measure, so a.e. convergence implies the one in measure.